# Android 5 kill alarmmanager task mysteriously

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have an android app that I wrote that uses AlarmManager to start a service to get some user informations (date, time, geographic position) and send these data to a internet server.

It's runs ok in Android 5, but after 7 days, the tasks scheduled by AlarmManager was stopped by S.O mysteriously.

I tested again several times and the same problem occurred in different days intervals.

This code firing the service:

```
public void ativaPendingIntentTransmite(){
    long tempoTransmite=System.currentTimeMillis(); 
    Intent intentTransmite = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiverTransmite.class);    
    pendingIntentTransmite = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,111, intentTransmite, 0);  
    alarmManagerTransmite = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE); 
    alarmManagerTransmite.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, tempoTransmite+1000*60*1, 1000*60*intervaloDeEnvio, pendingIntentTransmite);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

void setInexactRepeating (int type, 
                long triggerAtMillis, 
                long intervalMillis, 
                PendingIntent operation)

Instead of setRepeating()